# Get value of an array based on priority

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an object array based on priority I need to form an object array. Below is the code that I tried

```
var data_res = [{
   "ACTION_TYPE": "CREATE",
   "EXECUTION_TYPE": "N_EXECUTION"
   }, 
   { "ACTION_TYPE": "CREATE",
  "EXECUTION_TYPE": "R_PRE_EXECUTION"
   }
];
var arr =  ["R_PRE_EXECUTION", "S_PRE_EXECUTION", "N_EXECUTION"];
for (var i = 0; i < data_res.length; i++) {
for (var temp in arr) {
    if (data_res[i].RULE_EXECUTION_TYPE.indexOf(arr[temp])>-1) {
        console.log("data")
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data_res[temp]))
    }
}
```

The output that I'm getting is

```
data
undefined
data
{"ACTION_TYPE":"CREATE","EXECUTION_TYPE":"N_EXECUTION"}
```

I want the data based on my array `arr`. Like first `R_PRE_EXECUTION` data must be formed then `S_PRE_EXECUTION` and then `N_PRE_EXECUTION`, don't know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: `EXECUTION_TYPE": "R_PRE_EXECUTION"` this line there is missing quotes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want to sort `data_res` according to the order given by `arr`.

```js
var data_res = [{
    "ACTION_TYPE": "CREATE",
    "EXECUTION_TYPE": "N_EXECUTION"
}, {

    "ACTION_TYPE": "CREATE",
    "EXECUTION_TYPE": "R_PRE_EXECUTION"
}]

var arr = ["R_PRE_EXECUTION", "S_PRE_EXECUTION", "N_EXECUTION"];

data_res.sort(function(a, b) {
  var aKey = arr.indexOf(a.EXECUTION_TYPE);
  var bKey = arr.indexOf(b.EXECUTION_TYPE);  
  return aKey - bKey;
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(data_res,0,3));
```

Answer (score 2):

@georg's solution works great. Here's another way.

```js
var data_res = [{
    "ACTION_TYPE": "CREATE",
    "EXECUTION_TYPE": "N_EXECUTION"
  },
  {
    "ACTION_TYPE": "CREATE",
    "EXECUTION_TYPE": "R_PRE_EXECUTION"
}]

var arr = ["R_PRE_EXECUTION", "S_PRE_EXECUTION", "N_EXECUTION"];

var ordered = [];

for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data_res.length; i++) {
        if (arr[j].indexOf(data_res[i].EXECUTION_TYPE) > -1) {
            ordered.push(data_res[i]);
        }
    }
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(ordered, 0,3) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

This first `indexOf` matches with the third element of array, giving the index of `2`.
The data_res only have 2 elements hence the `data_res[temp]` gives `undefined` value.

You can do this

```
var data_res = [{
    "ACTION_TYPE": "CREATE",
    "EXECUTION_TYPE": "N_EXECUTION"
}, {

    "ACTION_TYPE": "CREATE",
    "EXECUTION_TYPE": "R_PRE_EXECUTION"
}]

var arr = ["R_PRE_EXECUTION", "S_PRE_EXECUTION", "N_EXECUTION"];

for (var i = 0; i < data_res.length; i++) {
        if ((arr.indexOf(data_res[i].EXECUTION_TYPE)) > -1) {
            console.log("data")
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data_res[i]))
        }
}
```